# Issue with compiling the qualcomm fastcv demo application

Tags: android, android-ndk

I followed all the steps as mentioned on developer site of Qualcomm.I am running the sample in debian os (linux). But not succeed.

https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/add-advanced-features/computer-vision-fastcv/getting-started-guide/compiling-and-running

My console log as below.

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project SplashScreen ****

make all 
Host OS was auto-detected: linux
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/apis/featureDetection/Android.mk:fastcvFeatDetect: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lfastcv    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/apis/imageProcessing/Android.mk:fastcvImgProc: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lfastcv    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/apis/imageTransformation/Android.mk:fastcvImgTransform: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lfastcv    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/utils/Android.mk:fastcvUtils: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/utils/Android.mk:fastcvUtils: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lfastcv    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/android/Jagdish/RNDPROJECTS/FastCVSamples-master'
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libfastcvFeatDetect.so
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lfastcv
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/android/Jagdish/RNDPROJECTS/FastCVSamples-master'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvFilterGaussian3x3u8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char*, int):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:4256: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvFilterGaussian3x3u8_v2'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvCornerFast9u8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int*):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:5929: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvCornerFast9u8_v2'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvCornerFast9InMasku8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:5959: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvCornerFast9InMasku8_v2'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvCornerHarrisu8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int*, int):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:6037: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvCornerHarrisu8'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvCornerHarrisInMasku8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:6088: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvCornerHarrisInMasku8'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvScaleDownBy2u8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char*):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:7008: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvScaleDownBy2u8_v2'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvScaleDownBy4u8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char*):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:7051: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvScaleDownBy4u8_v2'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvScaleDownu8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:7137: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvScaleDownu8_v2'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvCornerFast9Scoreu8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int*):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:7835: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvCornerFast9Scoreu8_v3'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function fcvCornerFast9InMaskScoreu8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, unsigned int*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:7867: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvCornerFast9InMaskScoreu8_v3'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function allocateMemory(int, int):jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:161: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemAlloc'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function allocateMemory(int, int):jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:168: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemAlloc'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function deallocateMemory():jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:194: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemFree'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function deallocateMemory():jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:199: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemFree'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function updateCorners(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:232: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemFree'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function updateCorners(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:242: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemAlloc'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function updateCorners(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:315: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemFree'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/fastcvFeatDetect/Corner.o: in function updateCorners(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int):jni/apis/featureDetection/Corner.cpp:326: error: undefined reference to 'fcvMemAlloc'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/libfastcvUtils.a(FastCVSampleRenderer.o): in function fcvColorYUV420toRGB565u8(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int*):jni/fastcv/fastcv.inl:4457: error: undefined reference to 'ppfcvColorYUV420toRGB565u8'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/libfastcvUtils.a(FastCVUtil.o): in function Java_com_qualcomm_fastcvdemo_utils_FastCVUtil_init:jni/utils/FastCVUtil.cpp:23: error: undefined reference to 'fcvSetOperationMode'
/home/android/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/libfastcvUtils.a(FastCVUtil.o): in function Java_com_qualcomm_fastcvdemo_utils_FastCVUtil_init:jni/utils/FastCVUtil.cpp:25: error: undefined reference to 'fcvGetVersion'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libfastcvFeatDetect.so] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

**** Build Finished ****
```

If anyone have idea. Please reply. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue

follow this exactly

Copy lib/libfastcv.a to your ndk lib directory (e.g /arch-arm/usr/**lib**)

Create a directory under the ndk include directory called fastcv. Copy the contents of inc directory from the installation directory to the new directory you just created under the ndk include directory (e.g /arch-arm/usr/**include/fastcv**)

both are diff locations. That was the mistake i made, i copied them to same location and now it worked perfectly :-)